# Will my German Aldi Talk work in Austria?

Tags: germany, cellphones, international-travel, austria

I'm going to be traveling to Vienna in a few days. Will my german Aldi Talk flat rate plan work in Austria? I just want to be able to use my phone to contact people there as well as use train apps through out the day. Going through the website has been frustrating, because I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 10):

YES AND NO.

Yes - the SIM card will work in Austria, but NO, you cannot use your normal flatrate. Aldi talk also offers [EU Internet Paket 60](http://www.alditalk.de/web/internet-prepaid-tarif/eu_internet_paket_60/) but it has only 60MB for 1 week and costs 4.99 EUR and [EU Sprach Paket 60](http://www.alditalk.de/talk/prepaid_tarife/eu_sprach_paket_60/) which has 60 Minutes for 1 week and costs also 4.99 EUR.